# Como somar elementos de uma lista e devolver o resultado como um número inteiro?

Tags: python

Preciso definir a função `soma_elementos`

Essa função recebe uma lista com números inteiros e devolve um número inteiro correspondente à soma dos elementos da lista recebida. Como eu faço isso?

```
def soma_elementos(lista):
    l = []
```

Answer (score 19):

Se isso não for um exercício para aprendizado, não reinvente a roda. Use a função [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), que serve exatamente pra isso.

```
soma = sum([1, 2, 3])
> 6
```

Se precisa mesmo refazer a função sum, tente assim:

```
def somar_elementos(lista):
  soma = 0
  for numero in lista:
    soma += numero
  return soma
```

Comment: Não tinha aprendido sobre a função sum ainda, mas deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Bons estudos.

Answer (score 0):

Fica ai a dica:

```py
lista=[1,4,10]

def soma(lista): #  somatorio de varios numeros de uma lista com for
    num=0
    for c in lista:
        num+=c
    print(num)
```

Você pode trocar o final por `return` dependendo do que você queira fazer

Comment: Mas já não responderam isso nas outras respostas?

Answer (score 0):

como nosso amigo @Antony Gabriel informou, deve ser uma pergunta mais didática e não tão funcional,

para somar todos elementos de um vetor o primeiro passo é percorre todos os elementos a 'n' maneiras de fazer porem  eu lhe indico o `for var in vetor`

ou seja para cada  elemento do `vetor` percorrendo do inicio ao fim, `var` vai receber aquele valor ou seja

```
for i in [1,4,3,6]:
   print(i)
```

- i vale 1
- i vale 4
- i vale 3
- i vale 6

você ja entendeu como percorrer o vetor o segundo passo é armazenar os valores pelo qual vc percorre então fora do for deve haver uma variavel que começa com 0 e quando vo for passando por cada elemento vai adicionando esse valor a variavel

```
total = 0

for i in [1,4,3,6]:
   total = total + i
```

- total = 1  pois é  (0+1)
- total = 5  pois é  (1+4)
- total = 8  pois é  (5+3)
- total = 14 pois é  (8+6)

o ultimo passo é jogar tudo para dentro de uma função sendo que observando os requisiutos ela tem que receber uma lista e retornar o numero da soma de todos os elementos logo ficará assim?

```
def soma_elementos(lista):
    total = 0
    for i in lista:
       total = total + i
    return total
```

Answer (score -1):

Como o Pablo mencionou, usando o built-in `sum(sua_lista)` vai somar o vetor de forma eficiente e simples.

Porem, o que muita gente desconhece e que usando o metodo sum da biblioteca numpy ( `numpy.sum(sua_lista)` ) vai produzir resultados mais rapidos caso voce use uma lista com muitos elementos ao inves de vetor.

No caso de lista, basta converter ela pra numpy array, ou voce pode simplesmente comecar a sua lista como numpy array, adicionar os elementos e usar a funcao acima que eu mencionei.

Maiores detalhes sobre o que falei podem ser observados nesse post do SO em ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922231/pythons-sum-vs-numpys-numpy-sum/10922478

Answer (score -2):

É a soma de todos os elementos da lista, não é?

**Tente isso:**

```
soma = 0
for i in range(len(l)):
    soma += l[i]
print(soma)
```

**Ficando assim:**

```
def soma_elementos(lista):
    l = lista
    return l

l = soma_elementos([1,2,3])
soma = 0
for i in range(len(l)):
    soma += l[i]
print(soma)
```

Comment: Não deu certo, não dá nenhum resultado

Comment: Sério? aqui eu tentei e deu certo, fala o erro que deu aí.

Comment: é porque na resposta da sempre zero, eu tenho que definir o soma_elementos, então quando eu abro soma_elementos([1,2,4]) por exemplo, o resultado é 0, deveria ser 7, né?

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta e você tenta novamente.

Comment: Antony na realidade a tua funcao `soma_elementos` nao está a fazer nada, só a receber e retornar o mesmo, podes retira-la e percorres logo a lista no for como o teu primeiro ex

Comment: Eu apenas coloquei a função que ele criou, ela realmente não faz nada, depende do que o Roberto irá fazer.

Answer (score -2):

```
def soma_elementos(lista):
    l = lista
    soma = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        soma += l[i]
    return soma

l = []
while True:
    x = int(input('Numero: '))
    if x == 0:
        break
    l.append(x)

l = soma_elementos(l)
print (l)
```

Comment: Funciona, mas recomendo estudar a resposta do Pablo para uma solução mais idiomática.

Answer (score -3):

Não esta errado,... a questão é que a FUNÇÃO retorna l, que é uma lista e a tela imprime o resultado da soma,..... quando na verdade o que se quer é que a função retorne o resultado da soma!

Veja o seguinte e implemente!

```
#_________________________________
#Definindo a função
def soma_elementos(lista):
    l = lista
    soma = 0 #iniciando a variavel soma
    for i in range(len(l)): #variacao de i de acordo com o tamanho de l
    soma += l[i] #soma dos elemenos relacionados ao indice i do laço for
return soma #retorno de funçao
#_________________________________

l = soma_elementos([1,2,3,1,3,2])
print (l) o código aqui
```